# UIPickerView with Text for Calculator

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, calculator

How do I have to format the code to get the values calculated without deleting the text? Here is an example:

```
var Value1 = ["10", "15", "20"]
var Value2 = ["1", "5", "30"]
```

This one works fine. I get it calculated but I want it to look like this for the picker view and text field.

```
var Value1 = ["10 Years old", "15 Years old", "20 Years old"]
var Value2 = ["1", "5", "30"]
```

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see an image of storyboard if you are using that, and perhaps the logic you are using to calculate the values.

I would advise doing something like this:

Where you decide what to display in the picker just add + "Years old" and it will add it onto whatever value you are calculating. I can provide exact code if you do the same.

Comment: Requests for information are better served in a comment. If you know what the original poster (OP) is asking and believe you have an idea how to format their code, then put that code in your answer.

Comment: @leanne Yeah apologies. I didn't have enough 'rep' to comment. I will update the answer when the question is updated. Cheers!